# Angular class directive on bootstrap ui modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a d**irective for vertically centering elements on page**, but when I'm trying to use it on a bootstrap.ui.modal, it doesn't work. 
restrict: 'AC',

Directive:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    console.log(element.prop('offsetHeight'));
    scope.$watch(function() {
        return [element[0].clientHeight].join('x');
    }, function(value) {
        var currentHeight = parseInt(value.split('x'));
        var currentMarginTop = ($window.innerHeight - currentHeight) / 2;
        element.css('margin-top', currentMarginTop + "px");
    });
}
```

Modal open function:

```
   $scope.openModal = function() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/app/modal.html',
        controller: 'modalCtrl',
        windowClass: 'bg-center-vertically'
    });
   }
```

It works fine if I put it on the regular index.html, **but on generated objects like modals, it doesn't work**.

I think this is a compiling issue, but I need to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to log the moment when the directive is called and when your modal are completly rendering ?

If the directive is called before, you must wait the complete loading of your modal to append your directive attibute/prepertie to your modal.

Comment: Yup, I've tried this. I think the problem is that the directive is declared inside the templateUrl and is not compiled by angular. 
But I really don't know how to solve it.

Comment: For a compiling problem you can look at [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Answer (score 0):

If it's compilation issue, then you can try something like this:

```
//instead of link:
compile: function (e) {
    e.trigger('create');
    return {
        post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.prop('offsetHeight'));
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return [element[0].clientHeight].join('x');
            }, function(value) {
                var currentHeight = parseInt(value.split('x'));
                var currentMarginTop = ($window.innerHeight - currentHeight) / 2;
                element.css('margin-top', currentMarginTop + "px");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did an example using your code.

Modal is working fine using directive inside **myModalContent.html**

This is the code in [jdffidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/pvv3m9cx/2/)

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
       <div ng-controller="CustomerController">  
            <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(customer)">{{ message }}</button> <br />
                <!--MODAL WINDOW--> 
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                    <div flash>
                        <h3>The Customer Name is: {{ customer }}</h3>
                    </div>                   
                </script>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance)
{
$scope.customer = "Gumarelo!";

});

app.controller('CustomerController', function($scope, $timeout, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.message = "Hello Customer. Click to center vertically your Name :D";

    // MODAL WINDOW
    $scope.open = function (_customer) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          controller: "ModalInstanceCtrl",
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          windowClass: 'bg-center-vertically'
             });

    };

});


app.directive("flash", function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: "AC",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element.prop('offsetHeight'));
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return [element[0].clientHeight].join('x');
            }, function(value) {
                var currentHeight = parseInt(value.split('x'));
                var currentMarginTop = ($window.innerHeight - currentHeight) / 2;
                element.css('margin-top', currentMarginTop + "px");
            });
        }
    };
});
```