# Directives as class in bootstrap ui modal do not compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass a directive as a class in the windowClass field but it doesn't seem to be compiled and therefore the directive is not called.

modal:

```
...
$modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modal.html',
      scope: scope,
      controller: 'myCtrl as controller',
      backdrop: false,
      windowClass: 'directive'
})
.result.then(function (data) {
     // something
});
...
```

directive:

```
...
.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var modal = element;
            console.log("directive called");
            // real code goes there
        }
    };
});
...
```

With this configuration, the directive never gets called.

I'm using a workaround at the moment but I am not satisfied with it:

directive:

```
...
.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var modal = element.parent().parent().parent();
            console.log("directive called");
            // real code goes there
        }
    };
});
...
```

modal.html:

```
<div directive>
     <!-- something -->
</div>
```

I found the same question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918537/angular-class-directive-on-bootstrap-ui-modal) but it doesn't have an answer other than my workaround, so I am reposting it with the appropriate tag: **angular-ui-bootstrap** as specified on the [github repo](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md), hoping to receive a better answer.

I am using:

- angular v1.3
- angular-ui/bootstrap v0.13.0 (last version)

Comment: `not satisfied with it`  ...why? That's not a very informative problem statement. Also, you haven't really given any indication as to what this directive is used for, or what the expectations were by using windowClass.

Comment: What I mean by this is that I don't like to select the modal box by doing: 
element.parent().parent().parent();
Instead of element.

The directive will be used for example to make the modal box resizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:  please see comment below.

Currently, we do not recompile the element.  Rather, we just call `$element.addClass` and pass in the user's specified value of `windowClass`.

However, we do think that there could be a use case for this and would like you to please enter a new issue [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues) if you don't mind.

Please link this SO post to the new issue.  Thanks.

Comment: After some discussion, this is not something we are going to support.  We recommend using a custom template if this is the behavior you want.  You can easily do this by using the `template` or `templateUrl` options in 0.13.4 which is currently scheduled to be released tomorrow.  You can also copy the existing template as a starting point, if you want.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Implementing your own solution shouldn't be difficult since the template will be compiled by the directive.  This will pick up your class directive.